# Creation/Annihilation operators for general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity

I anticipate that GR would require these operators to be such that no QFT cannot accommodate their structure, and remain normalizable.

Nonetheless, I would also expect that a blind construction of said operators straight from the Lagrangian or equations of motions outputs a result.

Is anyone here able to produce $\hat{a}^\dagger$ and $\hat{a}$ as would GR need them to be. Finally, I am curious in how exactly a QFT would fail from these annihilation/creation operators.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "producing" $a^\dagger$? What do expect to "fail" here? In a QFT you can express the fields in terms of c/a operators and vice versa, so all that happens is that you described a non-renormalizable theory with different variables!

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes; I am asking what is the formulation of GR, if any, in terms of $\hat{a}^\dagger$ and $\hat{a}$. What are the explicit expressions for them. Perhaps a reference?

Comment: And what problem do you have in writing down the non-renormalizable QFT that people mean when they say "GR is not renormalizable" and just doing the usual mode expansion for that?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I am curious to see if the Born rule produces a consistent probability density or probability current, or if the generality of GR transformations would break any possible such currents.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Do you have an introductory reference that construct the "non-renormalizable QFT with GR"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Is that the approach? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantum_gravity

Comment: A good start with many references to the original works is probably https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0206071